# Extract rows from numpy and add rows to specific indexes

Tags: numpy, bioinformatics

I have a really big 3D array (1103546X2504X3). These are genotype data, imported from VCF file. First I want to filter it, with my down data. After it, I would like to extract the needed rows, and add the missing one-s, but sorted. Right now my code is:
chr_pos is the position from my "reference" file, pos is the index position from the big array, and needed_index the rows I need.

```
needed_index = []
for i in range(len(chr_pos)):
    for k in range(len(pos)):
        if chr_pos[i] == k:
            needed_index.append(k)
```

After the extraction I check is there any missing row from the reference:

```
list_difference = [item for item in chr_pos if item not in needed_pos]
```

needed_pos was made with the same code, but with .append(pos[k]).

My questions would be:
How to extract specific array rows, according to the list needed_index or needed pos?
How to add the missing items to the array? It would be in the format indexesX2504X[0,0], where indexes is from list_difference, 2504 is the columns (sample numbers], and [0,0] is the value for every position i want to add.

Edit1: So basically I want to find the rows in the array, what i need (from a reference file), and if some of the positions are not in the main array, add them to the specific position with the 2504 column and [0,0] value as the third dimension

Comment: You could use ```np.take``` and specify the ```axis``` over which to select values. To address your first question, is the array you want to select from have size ```(1103546,2504,3)``` and you want to select elements from an 1d list of indices?

Comment: exactly. I know which lines I need, so basically i just need the big array's subset of (16500,2504,3). 509 rows are missing from this, that is the one i want to add to it.

Comment: So you have ```509``` indices? And you are adding items to each index?

Comment: basically in this main array I found 15895 rows i need (with the first code in the post), and there are 509 what i would need, but not in the main array. I want to extract the found ones from the main array, then add the 509 missing one, then order it according to 0th dimension (it's the position the genetic position of the variant).